# WPF Binding Between Controls

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a control on a page that contains a listbox. I also have another control which is a detail view.

Both of the controls have their own ViewModel which their child controls bind to.

Image Outlook. It has a list of folders and when you select a folder the detail control displays the contents of the folder.

How can I bind the detail control to the selected item in the list control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you have master-detail situation. Can you add list of details ViewModel as property of master ViewModel? That way you don't need anything special. It should work automatically. Something like this:

```
public class MyMasterViewModel
{
   public List<MyDetailViewModel> Details
   { get; set; }
}
```

Set collection of `MyMasterViewModel` as `DataContext` to both views and configure binding appropriately. As you move through master list, detail list will be automatically updated.
You'll probably need to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         DisplayMemberPath="Something"/>
```

Comment: My problem is that the master view is in a different control to the detail view. I will try your point about using the same ViewModel for both controls

Comment: If they are on same window then you can set `DataContext` on window. If you have other data context for window, see if you can put those two views together in some container (grid or some of the layout panels) and then set `DataContext` to that container.

Answer (score 0):

Use element-to-element binding, here as link to MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx with master-detail example.